# Define integer value in URLPattern(Django)

Tags: python, django

I want to use integer value in my url and I defined it as follows:

```
url(r'^1/do_something/(?P<n>\d+)/$', csrf_exempt(myapp.my_method)),
# Looks like "/1/do_something/n/"
```

In myapp.py, I've defined my method as follows:

```
def my_method(request, n):
    print type(n)  # which prints "<type 'unicode'>"
    # Do some other stuff
```

Is there something that I'm missing out when I defined url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter in the url is always a `str` or `unicode`, all you can do is `int（n）` to get a integer

For more info see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#captured-arguments-are-always-strings).

Comment: uhh, then what am I suppose to do when I want to pass both positive and negative numbers?

Comment: @ShrikantKakani You can accept str in url and treat them like integer in views no matter they are positive or negative.

Comment: I changed my url to url(r'^1/do_something/(?P<n>\w+)/$', csrf_exempt(myapp.my_method)), and then when I was passing '/1/do_something/-9/', it responded with response code 404 (which basically means that server has not found anything matching the Request-URI) :(

Comment: I think you mean `int(n)`.